# Como realizar una función lambda - Python

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero saber que error estoy cometiendo al usar esta función lambda.
Antes que nada estoy trabajando en Python con Pandas.

Tengo un listado de fechas con hora y me gustaría eliminar la hora con una función lambda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tenía en mente era algo así:

```
entradas = np.array(
    (lambda x: x[0:10], 
     e)
)
```

En el que cortaba el str con la fecha en cada entrada.

Imagino que podría hacerlo mediante la librería **datetime** (me refiero a lo de modificar el formato, no al aplicar la lambda).
Pero creo que este método sería menos costoso computacionalmente.

Agradeceria la ayuda, gracias.

Comment: La columna "date_of_entry" ¿es una cadena realmente? Tal vez sea un objeto `datetime` y entonces no te va a funcionar lo del slice. En cualquier caso, lo que te falta es _aplicar_ tu función lambda a todos los elementos de la columna, es decir: `entradas = e.map(lambda x: x[0:10])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

En este caso no necesitas utilizar `lambda` (Se podría utilizar pero es más eficiente utilizar el accesor `dt` si conviertes la columna a `datetime64`.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['2023-01-02 20:44:00', '2023-01-03 20:45:00', '2023-01-04 20:46:00']})

# Convertimos la columna a datetime64
df['Col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col'])

# Obtenemos solo la fecha y la ponemos en otra columna
df['Fecha'] = df['Col'].dt.date

print(df)
```

Esto imprime:

```
                  Col       Fecha
0 2023-01-02 20:44:00  2023-01-02
1 2023-01-03 20:45:00  2023-01-03
2 2023-01-04 20:46:00  2023-01-04
```

### Edición

Hice unas pruebas para medir el tiempo de ejecución entre el código anterior y la respuesta propuesta en el comentario de @Abulafia

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['2023-01-02 20:44:00', '2023-01-03 20:45:00', '2023-01-04 20:46:00']})

df['Fecha'] = df['Col'].map(lambda x: x[0:10])

print(df)
```

En ambos casos comenté la línea de `print(df)` y utilicé `timeit` para medir el tiempo de ejecución.

El código utilizando el accesor `dt`:

```
535 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

El código utilizando `lambda` y `map`

```
265 µs ± 871 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

En efecto, es más rápido utilizar `lambda` y `map`, pero depende de lo que deseas hacer con tus datos. Si en algún momento necesitas utilizar las propiedades de la fecha u hora, es mejor utilizar el accesor `dt` ya que facilita el manejo de los datos, si únicamente deseas obtener la fecha entonces con `lambda` y `map` sería suficiente.

### Edición 2

Hice otra prueba, pero ahora únicamente midiendo el tiempo de ejecución de la línea:

```
df['Fecha'] = df['Col'].dt.date
```

Y la línea:

```
df['Fecha'] = df['Col'].map(lambda x: x[0:10])
```

Ya que de otra forma estoy midiendo también el tiempo de convertir la columna a `datetime64` así que fue un error de mi parte haber hecho esa comparación.

El resultado del accesor es:

```
123 µs ± 343 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

El resultado de `lambda` y `map` es:

```
92.5 µs ± 732 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Por lo que se puede ver que utilizando el accesor es más rápido.